# Extract url of every image in library?

Tags: media-library

I'd like to make a PHP script to output the full-size URL of every image on the WordPress library.
How can i make a foreach of all images in the site?

Comment: you can get image url of an image using this `wp_get_attachment_image_src($post->ID);`. you can loop through all the ids ($post->ID) to get each and every image

Comment: You can also do it via WP CLI, attachments are just posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to get all attachments. You can use `get_posts` function for this:

```
$attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
) );
```

Then you have to loop through them and get their urls using `wp_get_attachment_url`:

```
foreach ( $attachments as $att ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_url( $att->ID );
}
```

Comment: Works well!! could you help me do it in chunks? since there's many images, it times out.

Comment: Solved with `'offset' => 20000,`